# AWS Flutter SDK to upload files to S3 bucket

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-s3

I'm looking for an AWS SDK to upload video files from the Flutter app. We are not using Cognito services, so Amplify is not possible. AWS SDK for S3 upload only supports native languages. Is there any way to upload the S3 files directly other than using the REST APIs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accomplish this programmatically without using one of the supported programming languages provided by the AWS SDK, you can implement your own REST logic. The REST endpoints supported by S3 are described here:

[Amazon S3 REST API Introduction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html)